# Rails 4 Heroku Assets not loading, though in heroku asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a problem with certain assets on heroku. (local environment is working fine)
The assets are in the pipeline. If I execute in the heroku rails console:

```
helper.asset_path("typicons.woff")
helper.asset_path("backgrounds/1.jpg")
```

I get the following response:

```
/assets/typicons-c2430aad2b6a33948dc064cfaee8ad65ff9e3ca439834f3aaa84abec3d10dea8.woff
/assets/backgrounds/1-c2098ff7e7fbb89b2d18e9cd9089f712f2b837265d1d2e4182c36c23392760c6.jpg
```

So I assume that the assets are in the heroku asset pipeline. As well by opening the url directly with the digest in it, I receive the file.

However if I try to reference the files in css or javascript like this:

```
  $('.top-content').backstretch("/assets/backgrounds/1.jpg");
```

The file does not load. As well opening /assets/backgrounds/1.jpg directly does not work. Referencing assets from .rb or .erb files works.

Please can someone tell me, what kind of config I have to change, so the URLs for assets work as well without the digest?

Thank you!

Comment: Try  `$ RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile` And `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. The assets are compiled and on heroku. I just cannot reference them from non-ruby files. And running the precompile commands on heroku bash didn't have any influence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a fairly standard asset pipeline setup, this passage from the Rails Guides should help:

> If you add an erb extension to a JavaScript asset, making it something such as application.js.erb, you can then use the asset_path helper in your JavaScript code:

-- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html (section 2.3.3)

In your example, add the `erb` extension to your JS file and then change the line to

```
 $('.top-content').backstretch(<%= asset_path("backgrounds/1.jpg") %>);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked as supposed. You only have to adapt the line to
` $('.top-content').backstretch('<%= asset_path("backgrounds/1.jpg") %>')`

1. Put the line in quotation marks
2. remove the assets
3. make sure there is no slash before the backgrounds/1.jpg path

Comment: Updated my answer; feel free to accept the answer if it worked/helped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Rails 4 does not support non-digested assets at all.(For whatever reason)
Here is a more thorough explanation on the issue: [Non Digested Asset Names in Rails 4](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/non-digested-asset-names-in-rails-4-your-options/)
My personal workaround was to add a public asset folder to my app:

```
public/assets/static/
```

and upload the assets required there. Since it was only about fonts and background images, which do not change often, it does not seem to be a problem. In the link above there are several other solutions proposed.